# Mouseout event does not trigger in IE 8

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I have a trailing object following after the mouse.
When the mouse gets out of the window, I want to hide it.
This works ok in other browsers, *but does not even trigger the event in IE8* >.<

If only I could trigger it, then guess it would work all right.

```
function mouseport(e){
    //alert('event triggered');
    if (document.all)  { //IF IE
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
    } else    {
        mouseX = (window.Event) ? e.clientX : event.clientX;
        mouseY = (window.Event) ? e.clientX : event.clientY;
    }
        if ((mouseY > 0 && mouseY < window.innerHeight)
        && (mouseX > 0 && mouseX < window.innerWidth)){
            return false;
        }else{
            if (follow) hidett()    //that's my hide function
        }
    }

// for IE compatability
if (!window.addEventListener) {
    window.attachEvent("mouseout", mouseport);
}
else {
    window.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseport, false);
}

if (window.Event) {
            if (window.captureEvents) { //doesn't run if IE
                document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEOUT);
            }
        }
```

Please help to find where I made a mistake that it does not trigger...

Comment: Use a JS library like jQuery to handle the platform incompatibilities for you.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't ask for jquery, please see the title ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.attachEvent("mouseout", mouseport);
```

should be

```
document.attachEvent("onmouseout", mouseport);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wrong, should be document.attachEvent. BUT thanks for pointing out

Comment: better? I didn't notice that. the missing 'on' stood out right away, also if you knew this was an issue why did you post the code as is? were you testing us or something? =P

Comment: yeah, see the link :)) IE 8 does not support mouse out on window. That I guessed, but I didn't know it was called 'onmouseout' :) **edit** no I wasn't testing anyone, lol :))

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

note: it is known to cause problems with certain sscroll bars.